# Conditionally apply either href or routerLink without *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

I have the following code in my Angular app template, which does not work as expected:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items"">
   <a class="link"
      [attr.href]="item.url"
      [routerLink]="item.routerLink"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
      tabindex="-1"
   >
     {{item.label}}
   </a>
<ng-container>
...
```

What I'm trying to do here is to iterate through an array of items and display list of links. The problem is that the item can either have `url` property, or `routerLink`. Depending on which property an item has, I need to either apply `href` attribute, or `routerLink`.

Is there a way to do that without using *ngIf which causes code duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
 <ng-container>
       <a class="link"
          [attr.href]="item.url ? item.url : ''"
          [routerLink]="item.routerLink ? item.routerLink: ''"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          tabindex="-1"
       >
         {{item.label}}
       </a>
    <ng-container>
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you move the strategy to the `component.ts`

```
<a (click)="navigateToLink(item)">
```

and

```
navigateToLink( item ){
   if( item.routerLink ){
      this.router.navigate([item.routerLink]);
   }else if( item.url ){
      this.windows.open(item.url);
   }
}
```

Comment: I literally thought the same thing, (that's what I would have done or just using the *ngIf. I don't know if he just doesn't want to use `ifs` for a particular reason

Comment: This is not recommended. href and click are different things, and click is likely to have poorer usability